# What is this pointy window tool?

Tags: windows, hand-tools

I found this in an old toolbox containing things used to fix windows-- glaziers points, spline rollers, glass cutters, etc.  Anyone know it is and what's it used for?

Mystery Tool
[image]

Comment: A picture will help.

Comment: Had to add "pointy" to the title and add markup to get the picture to show. "What is this tool?" is apparently already the name of another question.

Comment: Thanks for your help getting this posted. -Ed

Comment: The shape suggests it is used to remove window putty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a tool to remove window glaze (putty) from window frames. In the old days, windows were attached to wood frames with window glaze. Windows had individual frames for each piece of glass whereas nowadays there's one large sheet of glass and multiple strips of wood to make fake frames. Removing the glaze was hard and time consuming so we had this tool. It could be heated up to make the removal easier They've cheapened up the manufacturing of the tool, see photo below from home Depot.  I actually had one until my tools got stolen years ago.

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  I've got one or two of those tools too.  Those are the only ones I've had any luck using to remove glazing.  Maybe I'll try heating it up next time.  Thanks!

Comment: I've heard suggestions to use a hot air gun if you can't heat the tool. I've also been told that even professional glaziers sometimes break the glass when trying to remove old putty, so be prepared for that and don't be too embarrassed if it happens.